# How can I recondition old rubber seals?

Tags: materials

I have some rubber window seals that with age have become a bit hard and shiny, which is reducing their effectiveness. I can't replace these seals, so I would like to know -

Is there anything I can apply to the seals, so that they might regain some of their 'rubberiness'?

Comment: Where exactly are the seals?  Do you have pics you could share?

Comment: Don't have any pics unfortunately, but they are just rubber 'leaf' type seals attached to the sash, that seal against the frame.

Answer (score 2):

A [Google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1GPCK_enGB440GB440&gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=recondition+rubber) for "recondition rubber" brings up quite a few hits. However, I'd be surprised if any worked for any significant time.

Once rubber gets old and and particularly if it becomes perished it loses its elasticity and flexibility. You might be out of luck here.

Comment: I think he might be up the creek. :)

Comment: Yeah I had a look on Google - and found lot of recommendations for Petroleum Jelly - which I don't think is a good idea on rubber.  Had another look and saw silicone grease mentioned - will give this a try.

Answer (score 2):

I was browsing the [Cool Tools](http://www.kk.org/cooltools/archives/005287.php) site and came across this.  It's obviously designed as a protectant and not a reconditioner, but it gets rave reviews and might be worth a shot.

[Amazon link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0004ELKC4)

[image]